# How does ansible search namespaces for modules?

Tags: ansible, namespaces

I need to write ansible code compatible for multiple versions of ansible.  Older versions of ansible do not have namespaces and newer ones do.  In one instance, a role invoked an "ansible.builtin.yum" module, which failed in earlier versions of ansible.  For now, it was sufficient remove the prefix.  Where is the namespace behavior documented?  Presumably, un-prefixed module names are searched in a list of namespaces - what is that list?  Is there a namespace design document?  The closest I've been able to find to a namespace design document is https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/namespaces.html which makes invalid use-case assumptions.

Right now, removing the "ansible.builtin." from the names for such prefixed modules works, but I want to understand the namespace mechanism for when that stops working with newer versions of ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get depends on the configuration. See

- [DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-module-path)
- [COLLECTIONS_PATHS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths)

For example, if you use *yum*

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - yum:
        name: nginx
```

the first one found will be used

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t module -l | grep yum
ansible.builtin.yum
Manages packages with the ...
ansible.builtin.yum_repository
Add or re...
community.general.yum_versionlock
Locks / unlocks an installed package(s) from being updated b...
```

In a standard Ansible installation, there is only one *yum* among the installed modules. Therefore the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#ansible-builtin-yum-module-manages-packages-with-the-yum-package-manager) says:

> In most cases, you can use the short module name yum

The same rules will apply to your custom module:

- If you plan to use your module within your project(s) only put it into the *DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH*
- If you have more custom stuff (roles, modules, filters, plugins, ...) you might want to create a [collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_in_groups.html#creating-a-new-collection)
- If you think the module might be useful for others [contribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/community/contributions_collections.html#ansible-collections-contributor-guide) it.